# Issue with duplicate array values from preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

first time resorting to actually posting on SO.
Also sorry if this has been asked many times, i think ive about read most of them here, but still no dice.

I have a generated log file continaing text i wish to extract the line in the log file is this: 
{22:30:47} System:"Obambivas" StarPos:(-59.938,7.375,56.813)ly Body:13 RelPos:(-0.529636,-0.130899,0.838064)km NormalFlight

So far ive manaaged to get the matches via preg_match_all, and works fine.
However i really need each System:"" only once as the log may have several exacly the same.

Ive tried to use array_unique, but im fairly sure im using it wrong as it either retruns nothing or the same results, ie 10+ matches for each match found

So i need just each unique match from the matches found in the log file.

My code so far (sorry if its messy)
And thanks in advance

```
if (is_dir($log) && is_readable($log)) {


if (!$files = scandir($log, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING)) {

}
$newest_file = $files[0];

if (!$line = file($log . "/" . $newest_file)) {

} else {

  foreach ($line as $line_num => $line) {


        $pos = strpos($line, 'System:"');

        $pos2 = strrpos($line, "ProvingGround");

        if ($pos !== false && $pos2 === false) {

            preg_match_all("/\System:\"(.*?)\"/", $line, $matches);
            $cssystemname = $matches[1][0];
            $curSys["name"] = $cssystemname;


            preg_match_all("/\StarPos:\((.*?)\)/", $line, $matches2);
            $curSys["coordinates"] = $matches2[1][0];
            $coord_parts = explode(",", $curSys["coordinates"]);

            $curSys["x"] = $coord_parts[0];
            $curSys["y"] = $coord_parts[1];
            $curSys["z"] = $coord_parts[2];

            echo $curSys["name"].' | Coords: '.$curSys["x"].','.$curSys["y"].','.$curSys["z"].'<br />';

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of complete code, please mention your input and expected output as well.

Comment: Thankyou and i will in future, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added $hash array to avoid duplicates

```
if (is_dir($log) && is_readable($log)) {


if (!$files = scandir($log, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING)) {

}
$newest_file = $files[0];

if (!$line = file($log . "/" . $newest_file)) {

} else {

  $hash = array();

  foreach ($line as $line_num => $line) {


    $pos = strpos($line, 'System:"');

    $pos2 = strrpos($line, "ProvingGround");

    if ($pos !== false && $pos2 === false) {

        preg_match_all("/\System:\"(.*?)\"/", $line, $matches);
        $cssystemname = $matches[1][0];
        if ($hash[$cssystemname] == "")
        {
           $curSys["name"] = $cssystemname;


           preg_match_all("/\StarPos:\((.*?)\)/", $line, $matches2);
           $curSys["coordinates"] = $matches2[1][0];
           $coord_parts = explode(",", $curSys["coordinates"]);

           $curSys["x"] = $coord_parts[0];
           $curSys["y"] = $coord_parts[1];
           $curSys["z"] = $coord_parts[2];

           echo $curSys["name"].' | Coords: '.$curSys["x"].','.$curSys["y"].','.$curSys["z"].'<br />';

    }
   } else $hash[$cssystemname] = "inhash";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the fast reply, this works fine i see only each unique match now, but im getting php notices, the first is:
Notice: Undefined variable: cssystemname in C:\wamp64\www\elite\update_logs.php on line 71
and second: 
Notice: Undefined index: Obambivas in C:\wamp64\www\elite\update_logs.php on line 55

Apart from these its working fine, thankyou.

Comment: replace if ($hash[$cssystemname] == "") to if (!isset($hash[$cssystemname]))

Comment: Thankyou thats sorted the hash array index issue.